# A comprehension question to conditional heteroscedasticity/GARCH

Tags: variance, arima, model, heteroscedasticity, garch

I have a time series with strong seasonality. At specific time periods/seasons there is also a stronger Variance than in other time periods/seasons. Is that an example of conditional Heteroscedasticity which can be modeled by GARCH?

(i want to apply a seasonal ARIMA-GARCH Model on this data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seasonally-varying conditional variance may or may not be combined with a GARCH model.

Let me give an example of an ARMA(1,1) process with seasonally-varying conditional variance but without a GARCH pattern.
(I will skip the seasonal component in the conditional mean of the process for brevity.)

$$ x_t - \phi_1 x_{t-1} = r_t + \theta_1 r_{t-1} $$
$$ r_t = \sigma_t \varepsilon_t $$
$$ \sigma_t = \sigma + s_t  $$

Here $\varepsilon_t$ is a conditionally homoskedastic shock with unit variance, $\sigma_t$ is the conditional standard deviation of $r_t$, $\sigma$ is a base level of variance and $s_t$ is a seasonal component (specific to the season).

If you replace the last equation by

$$ \sigma_t = \tilde{\sigma_t} + s_t $$

$$ \tilde{\sigma}_t^2 = \omega + \alpha_1 r_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \tilde{\sigma}_{t-1}^2 $$

where $\omega$ is the base level of variance, you will get a GARCH pattern extra to the seasonality in the conditional variance.

How should you choose between the two models in practice? Try them out and see which one seems more adequate (for example, has better-behaved residuals and lower AIC/BIC values).